# How do I define the starting line for preg_match in PHP?

Tags: php, preg-match-all

Im using the preg_match to find a certain word in a text file. However, I want to define the starting line from which preg_match starts its search. How can I make preg_match to ignore the first 5 lines?
Additionally, I have a code which will automatically delete the preg_matched word from the file, so im not sure a "start from keyword" would work here.

Heres the code im using.

```
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
$pattern = "/\b$pattern\b/m";
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches))
```

Comment: Better use `file()` to get an array with each line as one entry, then do your regex stuff on index 5 (_ignore the first 5 lines_).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prefixing your pattern with

```
^((.*)\n){5}\K
```

should discard the first 5 rows of any search please see the demo below

https://regex101.com/r/wFqazl/2

Your code would then look like this

```
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
$pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
$pattern = "/^((.*)\n){5}\K\b$pattern\b/m";
if(preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go this way, like @JustOnUnderMillions suggested

```
$input = file($file);
$output = array_slice($input, 5); // cut off first 5 lines
$output = implode("\n", $output); // join left lines into one string

// do your preg_* functions on output
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ignore the first 5 lines then

```
"/^(?:.*?\n){5,5}[^\n]/"
```

should do it.

https://regex101.com/r/TEBTYt/1